# JS Session Time Not working if the Tab Is not focus of My web SIte Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

When my tab is not focused the session timer stops. I want it to run if my site is open in the browser. Any solution?

```
function startTimer() {
    timeLimitInSeconds--;
    var minutes = Math.floor(timeLimitInSeconds / 60);
    var seconds = timeLimitInSeconds % 60;
    if (minutes == 1 && seconds == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Your session will logout within 1 minute. Do you want to continue?',
            // text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes ',
            cancelButtonText: 'No',
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            allowEscapeKey: false
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                console.log("Session Continue Windows Reload..")
                window.location.reload()
            } else {
                window.location = "${sessionScope.clienturl}/logout";
            }
        })
    } else if (minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0) {
        console.log("Logout Fired After Time Out")
        window.location = "/logout";
    }

    if (timeLimitInSeconds < 0) {
        timerElement.textContent = '00:00';
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        return;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = '0' + seconds;
    }

    timerElement.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;


}
```

Comment: Modern browsers often don't continue processing/rendering a page that isn't focused.  (Additionally, it's also worth noting that the code shown attempts to clear a timer that was never started in the first place...)

Comment: Rather than a timer, store a start time in local storage or a cookie and compare to that. JavaScript is notoriously bad at counting time anyway. If you want true security, store the time on the backend, not in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

The issue likely stems from the way browsers handle timers and intervals when a tab is not in focus. Browsers often throttle or pause timers to conserve resources for inactive tabs. This behavior can affect your session management if you rely on client-side JavaScript timers.

Here are a few approach you can consider to handle this situation:

Use Server-Side Session Management:
Consider managing your sessions on the server side. This approach is more reliable because it doesn't depend on client-side JavaScript. When the user interacts with your site, send requests to the server to update the session state.
I hope this will Help You